Ubuntu Permission Denied when running a C# .net program
Whenever I run this script:
using System;

namespace learningCSharp{
    class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        }
    }
}

It throws this error at me:

Unhandled exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (13): An error occurred trying to start process '/media/emerson-rexroth/BRYCESTUFF/code/learningC#/bin/Debug/net8.0/learningC#' with working directory '/media/emerson-rexroth/BRYCESTUFF/code/learningC#'. Permission denied
at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Execute(Action`1 processStarted)
at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.RunCommand.Execute()
at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.Invoke(ParseResult parseResult)
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, TimeSpan startupTime, ITelemetry telemetryClient)

I run the script using the vscode terminal using dotnet run. I downloaded .net using the microsoft tutorial for Ubuntu 20.04, but not through WSL(Im new to Ubuntu/Linux). Any help is appreciated!
I have Uninstalled .net and reinstalled it. I expected the script to run like when I used to use windows, but now this is happening.

Try running a dotnet clean followed by a dotnet run
Because you look like you are mounting your Source folder from your windows system (and so Debug/net8.0 folder) the executable likely doesn't have the right permissions.
If that doesn't work ensure you can actually write to the mounted folder.
cd /media/emerson-rexroth/BRYCESTUFF/code/learningC#
touch somefile.txt
if creating a new file doesn't work, then you need to fix how your source folder is mounted.
running mount and looking at the output might be a good place to start.
